# Laravel - How to resolve error 404 route problem

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel-5.8 project as shown here:

Controller: Admin/LeavesController

```
use App\Models\Leave;

class LeavesController extends Controller
{
public function leave_review()
{
 try {  
       $leaves                  = Leave::get();

        return view('admin.leaves.leave_review')
                ->with(['leaves', $leaves); 
    } catch (Exception $exception) {

        Session::flash('error', 'Action failed! Please try again');
        return back();
        }                     
}
```

route/web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('admin/leaves/leave_review', 'LeavesController@leave_review')->name('leaves.leave_review');
});
```

The view folder is as this:

views->admin->leaves->leave_review.blade.php

layout/sidebar:

```
             <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="{{ route("admin.leaves.leave_review") }}" class="nav-link {{ request()->is('admin.leaves') || request()->is('admin.leaves/*') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                 <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                 <p>
                   <span>Leave-Review</span>
                 </p>
               </a>
```

I have my php artisan route:list

> | GET|HEAD                               | admin/admin/leaves/leave_review           | admin.leaves.leave_review             | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LeavesController@self_review               | web,auth           |

When I rendered the page, though it loaded, but in the route admin is repeated twice:

> http://localhost:8888/hrm/admin/admin/leaves/leave_review

That is, admin/admin

When I removed admin prefix and have the route this way:

So remove it from your route, change it to this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
   Route::get('leaves/leave_review', 'LeavesController@leave_review')->name('leaves.leave_review');
});
```

I got another error:

error 404 page not found and the uri changed to:

> http://localhost:8888/hrm/admin/admin/leaves/leave_review

Why and how do I correct this?

Thank you

Comment: you've posted how you are generating your routes for consumption (routes.web) but you have not shown how you are creating the actual links to the routes (blade file probably). Your second route group is correct, you don't want the duplicate admin/admin/ (i'd imagine). Fix whatever is generating the link itself to not generate /hrm/admin/admin and you'll be gravy

Comment: In your view do `route('leaves.leave_review')` instead of **admin.leaves.leave_review**. And you should run `php artisan route:clear` after changing the route.

Comment: @GiovanniS - I rendered the view from the sidebar. And that is shown in the code

Answer (score 0):

Because now your route is **admin/leaves/leave_review** not **admin/admin/leaves/leave_review**.

If you frequently change your route links you can consider using route names inside your view as **route('leaves.leave_review')**. this way if name is unchanged you will always get the route associated with that name.